# Unable to set Azure Active Directory Admin as user greyed out?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-activedirectory

I have a SQL Server which I want to enable Azure AD authentication with. On the overview of the server, it shows `Active Directory Admin` as Not Configured. If I click on that, I am taken to this page:

[image]

I have blanked out my details, but you can see that I am unable to select my account. Why would this be?

Answer (score 3):

> but you can see that I am unable to select my account. Why would this
>   be?

Currently, Microsoft accounts (like live.com, outlook.com) **cannot** be set as admin. Only users and security groups within your organization can be set as admin.

[image]

So, we should select other account to set as admin.

Comment: Nope, this is my company account with custom domain

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Do you mean that account sync from your on-prem AD?

Comment: No, it is all online, it has an associated office subscription etc. Microsoft Cloud services

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Does that account can login Azure portal and read the resource group?

Comment: Yes, it is the one currently logged in when I am looking at the SQL settings

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Do you mean you are use this account (guest) to login azure portal to set this sql server?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by guest? But I am trying to set the current account to be AD admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63838/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-george-edwards).

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I mean does this account is the admin of this subscription? we can discuss it in this chat room.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards can you set another account as the admin?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Did you solve this problem? if yes, could you please share your solution?